# dijit tree insert and delete nodes

Tags: php, dojo, tree

Has anyone got a working example on howto insert and delete nodes in a tree that is directly connected to a datastore (FileItemWriteSotre) without explicit declaring a Model?

I tried everything I found searching net and forums, nothing works. Inserting the node into the datastore seems to work but does not insert a node in the Tree.

Add Infos: I have a PHP tree object that constructs declarative Tree (HTML/JS Code) and creates a json content and replies to a AJAX request. Since I am neary done with the project, i will not apply big changes. But it would improve usability quite a lot if I had not to rebuild the tree on every insert oder delete. Having managed to focus a node even if it is currently not visible already helped a lot making the UI more proefessional, solving the above problem would be the icing on the cake!

Thanks in advance

Micha

Answer (score 1):

just invoke newItem and deleteItem on data store

Comment: if you do that on a JsonRest Store you also invoke a delete on the server.